# Gyroscope on STM32F429-DISC1 is behaving strangely

Tags: c, stm32, gyroscope, stm32f4discovery

I'm quite new in STM32 world, and I have a problem with the on-board L3GD20 gyroscope on teh STM32F429-DISC1 board.

I had troubles in getting it running (the gyroscope was constantly sending the same data, even after reset or power down) and after I finally managed to get it working (by sending instructions a couple of times), I saw strange results (both on x-axis, y and z) (see graph below).

Am I missing something, or should I do something with the raw data, that will smooth it? Is there a possibility, that the IC is defective?

I am using Atollic TrueStudio v9.0 for STM32 with STM32F429-DISC1.

Here is my code:

```
#include "stm32f4xx.h"
#include "stm32f429i_discovery.h"
#include "stdio.h"
volatile uint32_t elapsed = 0;

#define CS_gyro_start   GPIO_ResetBits( GPIOC, GPIO_Pin_1 )
#define CS_gyro_stop    GPIO_SetBits( GPIOC, GPIO_Pin_1 )

void DelayMS( int time ){
    elapsed = time;
    while( elapsed > 0 );
}

void SysTick_Handler(){
    if( elapsed > 0 ) --elapsed;
}

void SendChar( char ch ){
    while( USART_GetFlagStatus( USART1, USART_FLAG_TXE ) == RESET ){}
    USART_SendData( USART1, ch );
}
void sendString( const char *s ){
    while( *s ){
        SendChar( *s++ );
    }
}
int _write( int file, char *ptr, int len ){
    sendString( ptr );
return len;
}  //sadly this doesn't work with float variables


void initialize( void ){
    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd( RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOA |
                            RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOC |
                            RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOF, ENABLE );

    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd( RCC_APB2Periph_SPI5 |
                            RCC_APB2Periph_SYSCFG |
                            RCC_APB2Periph_USART1, ENABLE );

    GPIO_InitTypeDef        gpio;
    USART_InitTypeDef       usart;
    SPI_InitTypeDef         spi;

    GPIO_StructInit(    &gpio );
    USART_StructInit(   &usart );
    SPI_StructInit(     &spi );

//usart
    GPIO_PinAFConfig( GPIOA, GPIO_PinSource10, GPIO_AF_USART1 );
    GPIO_PinAFConfig( GPIOA, GPIO_PinSource9, GPIO_AF_USART1 );

    gpio.GPIO_Mode =        GPIO_Mode_AF;
    gpio.GPIO_OType =       GPIO_OType_PP;
    gpio.GPIO_PuPd =        GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
    gpio.GPIO_Pin =         GPIO_Pin_9 | GPIO_Pin_10;
    GPIO_Init( GPIOA, &gpio );

    usart.USART_BaudRate =  115200;
    USART_Init( USART1, &usart );

    USART_Cmd( USART1, ENABLE );

//spi
    GPIO_PinAFConfig( GPIOF, GPIO_PinSource7, GPIO_AF_SPI5 );
    GPIO_PinAFConfig( GPIOF, GPIO_PinSource9, GPIO_AF_SPI5 );
    GPIO_PinAFConfig( GPIOF, GPIO_PinSource8, GPIO_AF_SPI5 );

    //SS
    gpio.GPIO_Pin =     GPIO_Pin_1;
    gpio.GPIO_Mode =    GPIO_Mode_OUT;
    gpio.GPIO_OType =   GPIO_OType_PP;
    gpio.GPIO_PuPd =    GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
    GPIO_Init( GPIOC, &gpio );
    GPIO_SetBits( GPIOC, GPIO_Pin_1 );

    //SCK, MOSI
    gpio.GPIO_Pin =     GPIO_Pin_9 | GPIO_Pin_7;
    gpio.GPIO_OType =   GPIO_OType_PP;
    gpio.GPIO_Mode =    GPIO_Mode_AF;
    gpio.GPIO_Speed =   GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
    gpio.GPIO_PuPd =    GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
    GPIO_Init( GPIOF, &gpio );

    //MISO
    gpio.GPIO_Pin =     GPIO_Pin_8;
    gpio.GPIO_OType =   GPIO_OType_PP;
    gpio.GPIO_Mode =    GPIO_Mode_AF;
    gpio.GPIO_Speed =   GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
    gpio.GPIO_PuPd =    GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
    GPIO_Init( GPIOF, &gpio );

    spi.SPI_Mode =                  SPI_Mode_Master;
    spi.SPI_NSS =                   SPI_NSS_Soft;
    spi.SPI_BaudRatePrescaler =     SPI_BaudRatePrescaler_256;
    SPI_Init( SPI5, &spi );
    SPI_Cmd( SPI5, ENABLE );

}


uint8_t SPI_sendByte( uint8_t byte_ ){
    while( SPI_I2S_GetFlagStatus( SPI5, SPI_I2S_FLAG_TXE ) == RESET ){}
    SPI_I2S_SendData( SPI5, byte_ );

    while( SPI_I2S_GetFlagStatus( SPI5, SPI_I2S_FLAG_RXNE ) == RESET ){}
return SPI_I2S_ReceiveData( SPI5 );
}

void SPI_writeData( uint8_t address, uint8_t byteToWrite ){
    CS_gyro_start;
        SPI_sendByte( address );
        SPI_sendByte( byteToWrite );
    CS_gyro_stop;
}

void GetGyroValues( uint16_t *x, uint16_t *y, uint16_t *z ){
    CS_gyro_start;
        SPI_sendByte( 0x29 | 0x80 );
        *x = SPI_sendByte( 0xff );
    CS_gyro_stop;
    CS_gyro_start;
        SPI_sendByte( 0x28 | 0x80 );
        *x |= (SPI_sendByte( 0xff ) << 8);
    CS_gyro_stop;

    CS_gyro_start;
        SPI_sendByte( 0x2B | 0x80 );
        *y = SPI_sendByte( 0xff );
    CS_gyro_stop;
    CS_gyro_start;
        SPI_sendByte( 0x2A | 0x80 );
        *y |= (SPI_sendByte( 0xff ) << 8);
    CS_gyro_stop;

    CS_gyro_start;
        SPI_sendByte( 0x2D | 0x80 );
        *z = SPI_sendByte( 0xff );
    CS_gyro_stop;
    CS_gyro_start;
        SPI_sendByte( 0x2C | 0x80 );
        *z |= (SPI_sendByte( 0xff ) << 8);
    CS_gyro_stop;
}

int main( void ){
    SysTick_Config( SystemCoreClock / 1000 );
    initialize();

    SPI_writeData(0x20, 0xff);  //power on, settings from TM-library & datasheet
    SPI_writeData(0x21, 0x00);  //high-pass filter settings
    SPI_writeData(0x24, 0x10);  //high-pass filter en
    SPI_writeData(0x23, 0x20);  //scale 2000

    uint16_t x, y, z;
    while( 1 ){
        GetGyroValues( &x, &y, &z );
        printf( "x: %d\r\n", x );

        DelayMS( 100 );

    }
}


uint32_t sEE_TIMEOUT_UserCallback(void)
{
  /* TODO, implement your code here */
  while (1)
  {
  }
}//   This is required by Atollic
```

Here is a sample graph showing the changes on x-axis. (the discovery board was more or less at 45 degrees, when it's at 0 degrees - laying down, then the output is a stable 65000)
[image: COM port view]

Comment: `void DelayMS( int time ){
    elapsed = time;
    while( elapsed > 0 );
}` there could be a `do{` missinghere.

Comment: @wildplasser : No, it is fine.  It is just an empty loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [L3GD20 app note](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/2c/d9/a7/f8/43/48/48/64/DM00119036.pdf/files/DM00119036.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00119036.pdf):

[image]

Note the last part ***"expressed as a two’s complement number"***; you are incorrectly interpreting the data as *unsigned*.  It looks like the value is hovering around zero; or actually it looks like you are holding it rather unsteadily in a position, but certainly not rotating it continuously as a steady rate.  The device is a *gyroscope* not an *accelerometer*.  It measures angular velocity *not* acceleration (or tilt - i.e. acceleration due to gravity).  While stationary you would expect zero on all axes. What your graph shows is probably your hand shaking trying to hold it at 45 degrees.

```
void GetGyroValues( int16_t *x, int16_t *y, int16_t *z )
```

should be more sucessful, and of course:

```
    int16_t x, y, z;
```

You can get an approximate measure of *change of angle* by integrating angular velocity, but not absolute angle.  Even then you may have to calibrate frequently for zero - a small non-zero bias in integration will manifest itself as a false slow rotation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was using unsigned variables, because I really like the fact, that you can save a little bit of memory, and I was abusing unsigned  types by using them everywhere. That ended up in a big facepalm, but i digress. I changed the variable types from uint16_t to int16_t and I also changed the order (Tom Kuschel pointed this out) and I got this result: https://imgur.com/qSV0d8C Is this the right behavior? At least it looks much better, than before.

Comment: OK, it seems that this is the right output data, I checked it with my phone's gyro and the behavior is the same, Thank you one more time.

Comment: @KamilWitek  : in what way does using unsigned types save memory!?  Hint: it doesn&#39;t.

Comment: I know, that it's kind of counter-intuitive, but I meant that in a lot of cases we use only positive values, and if I declare a variable as ex. int then I lose half of it for nothing and by using unsigned type I can use every bit to store a value. That is exactly what I meant. English is not my native language, so it might have sounded strangely at first. It's not necessary to apply this everywhere, but I really like to write as efficient and easy to read programs, as I can. I hope that this cleared some things :). Thank you for the responses, have a nice day.

Comment: @KamilWitek ; Take my advice from many years experience - don't do that!  Think about it - it only saves memory in circumstances where the max value of the signed type is less than the range necessary _and_ you don't need negative values, and won't be using such values in arithmetic involving signed values.  It is easier to determine the rare individual cases where there is some benefit, than it is to just blindly apply it everywhere _without_ such careful analysis.  It may be applicable to array indexes and iteration counters, but is most often a bad idea for arithmetic objects.

Comment: OK, I will stop blindly using unsigned types. Sorry for that, it's just the lack of experience and the fact, that I'm still learning. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

As from the datasheet [L3GD20](http://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/l3gd20.pdf), table 17, the OUT_XL is at address 0x28 and OUT_XH at address 0x29.
So you have to left shift the value with address 0x29 not 0x28 and vica versa.
This also with Y and Z values.

```
void GetGyroValues( int16_t *x, int16_t *y, int16_t *z ){
    CS_gyro_start;
    SPI_sendByte( 0x28 | 0x80 );
    *x = SPI_sendByte( 0xff );
    CS_gyro_stop;
    CS_gyro_start;
    SPI_sendByte( 0x29 | 0x80 );
    *x |= (SPI_sendByte( 0xff ) << 8);
    CS_gyro_stop;

    CS_gyro_start;
    SPI_sendByte( 0x2A | 0x80 );
    *y = SPI_sendByte( 0xff );
    CS_gyro_stop;
    CS_gyro_start;
    SPI_sendByte( 0x2B | 0x80 );
    *y |= (SPI_sendByte( 0xff ) << 8);
    CS_gyro_stop;

    CS_gyro_start;
    SPI_sendByte( 0x2C | 0x80 );
    *z = SPI_sendByte( 0xff );
    CS_gyro_stop;
    CS_gyro_start;
    SPI_sendByte( 0x2D | 0x80 );
    *z |= (SPI_sendByte( 0xff ) << 8);
    CS_gyro_stop;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I used the wrong order, because I thought that the values will be "magically" centered near 32000, so the half of a 16 bit unsigned integer, and while debugging I found out, that the second values (H) were equal to 0 or to 255, so I thought that these values must have been from the LSB part of an unsigned integer. Lessons learned...